# Elementary tranformations in matrix

Tags: matrix-rank

Very often we use elementary transformations to find rank of matrices. 
Which of the following transformations are correct? I guess that only 1 is correct and 2, 3 are wrong. Am I right?

1. $R_2\to R_2-kR_3$
2. $R_2\to 2R_2-kR_3$
3. $R_2\to -R_2-kR_3$

Comment: In case of simplification of determinants, can we apply all these three. Or only first one is correct in this case?

Comment: I have doubt in case of determinant

Answer (score 0):

They're not wrong, they're just a combination of two separate elementary row operations.

The 3 elementary row operations are (1) interchanging rows, (2) adding a multiple of one row to another, and (3) multiplying a row by a nonzero constant. Your number 2 and 3 are two row operations of types (2) and (3).